# Arduino Turn on a led with the PCA9865

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using the PCA9865 to light a led

**My circuit** [image]

**Arduino to PCA9865**
A5 > SLC A4 > SDA 5V > 5V GND > GND and 
5 volts from a battery

[image]

**My code:**

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>

// called this way, it uses the default address 0x40
Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

void setup()
{
  pwm.begin();
  pwm.setPWMFreq(60);  //~60 Hz updates
}


void loop()
{
  int pin = 0;
  pwm.setPWM(pin, 4096, 0);
}
```

**the led does not light**

Comment: add a current limiting resistor in series with the LED. could you light the LED with Uno directly? set higher freequency

Comment: really? you wired it to 4 and 5 instead of A4 and A5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments check resistor/led AND make sure you get power/GND to the terminal on the PCA board as this is needed for powering servos/leds/motors hanging on the board. I use about 10 on my layout and they are fantastic for powering all kind of appliancies. I patched the lib but in your case this is overkill. Instead of

```
void setPWM(uint8_t num, uint16_t on, uint16_t off);
```

you could also try

```
void setPin(uint8_t num, uint16_t val, bool invert=false);
```

but that is not the problem here
**EDIT**
Thanks for the foto now its clear why not. You have to connect A4 (UNO SCA) -  SCA (PCA9865)  AND A5 (UNO SCL) - SCL (PCA9865) see diagram:

[image: UNO to PCA9865]

Comment: I added a photo of my circuit